# Setting connectionPool crashes Slick 3.0

Tags: mysql, scala, connection-pooling, slick

I'm using Slick 3.0 with MySql and I'm getting terrible performance, which I want to tune. I initialize the database with

```
val db = Database.forConfig("horridDBStuff")
```

Then in `application.conf` I have

```
horridDBStuff = {
    url = "jdbc:mysql://my.db.address:3306/myschema"
    driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    connectionPool = disabled
    keepAliveConnection = true
    properties = {
        user = "me"
        password = "me"
    }
}
```

Slick documentation says that in deployment you should enable the connection pool, so that's what I want to try. However it doesn't give an example of how to do this. I've tried commenting the line out, or replacing with `connectionPool = enabled`, or `connectionPool = 10`. All of these just crash Slick with a multi-page error stack. Anyone know how to properly configure the connectionPool? (Any other performance suggestions would also be appreciated - I've tried adding `numThreads=10` which doesn't seem to improve things much, but at least that doesn't crash it ;)

Comment: That multi page error stack would probably contain some hint about what is wrong. Read it carefully top down and see what the exception message says, if that doesn't help, put it somewhere, like a gist and share it here.

Comment: You're right. I'd left out the HikariCP dependency in my build.sbt, as I described in comment below. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slick 3.0 uses [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) by default.  There's a ton of documentation on its [project page](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP) for tuning information.  As long as you don't mind using HikariCP, you should not need a connectionPool param at all.

That being said, you could could set connectionPool = HikariCP in your application.conf and that will not throw an error, though other than self-documentation, this seems redundant.

Comment: Thanks. Problem was that I hadn't included HikariCP in build.sbt, so it was crashing unless I had `connectionPool = disabled`. My build.sbt now has `"com.zaxxer" % "HikariCP" % "2.3.3"` which I'd overlooked on the Slick docs. It now works fine and I got an immediate speedup of 5x.