# Slick 3.0 Connection to MySQL with connection pool enabled

Tags: scala, slick-3.0

I have the following application.conf

```
mysql {
  driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
  url = "jdbc:mysql://myserver:3306/mydb"
  user = "foo"
  password = "bar"
  keepAliveConnection = true
  connectionPool = enabled
}
```

when I do `Database.forConfig("mysql")` I get an exception

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: enabled
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:530)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at slick.util.ClassLoaderUtil$$anon$1.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.scala:17)
        at slick.jdbc.JdbcDataSource$.loadFactory$1(JdbcDataSource.scala:37)
        at slick.jdbc.JdbcDataSource$.forConfig(JdbcDataSource.scala:46)
        at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$DatabaseFactoryDef.forConfig(JdbcBackend.scala:288)
        at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$DatabaseFactoryDef.forConfig$(JdbcBackend.scala:285)
        at slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend$$anon$3.forConfig(JdbcBackend.scala:33)
        at com.abhi.CodeGen$.delayedEndpoint$com$abhi$CodeGen$1(CodeGen.scala:25)
        at com.abhi.CodeGen$delayedInit$body.apply(CodeGen.scala:15)
        at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
        at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:34)
```

If I change my config to

```
mysql {
  driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
  url = "jdbc:mysql://myserver:3306/mydb"
  user = "foo"
  password = "bar"
  keepAliveConnection = true
  connectionPool = disabled
}
```

Then everything works.

But why do I get this wierd error message if I try to establish a connection with connection pool enabled?

Edit: This is my build.sbt

```
   "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.2.0",
   "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-codegen" % "3.2.0",
   "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.38",
   "com.zaxxer" % "HikariCP" % "2.6.3"
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you haven't dependency in classpath for some jar with pool implementation, such as Hikari. Possible duplicate of [Setting connectionPool crashes Slick 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31733586/setting-connectionpool-crashes-slick-3-0)

Comment: I have the HikariCP in my build.sbt. I still get the error